# python programming text file and script

Tags: python-3.x

I need to take a value from a text for the calculations in script
I tried,

```
file = open("inventory.txt","r")
line = file.readlines()
file.close()
print(line[1])
```

But it reads that line together with the value.
I need to take that value out and use in my calculations
I also need to know how to import a number which is in the print statement of a text file of python to script

Comment: What does `inventory.txt` look like?

Comment: Can you give a little example? Like `bread,5.5\ndonkey,102`...

Comment: This is my invent txt file

Comment: file.write('***Invent***\n')
# Including the contents

file.write('egg, 10 \n')
file.write('flour, 10 \n')
file.write('icing, 10 \n')
file.close()

Comment: If anyone having a clue please let me know